# Centos has logs with two "hours", UTC and GMT, why?

Tags: logging, centos, time-zone

my logs contain currently two timezones, do you have an idea from where it comes and how to fix this? It's the first time I see this on a system.

The system is running inside a Virtuozzo container with CentOS 5.

Here is a small snippet:

```
May 11 13:51:37 dido sshd[13443]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=XXXXXXXXXXX  user=root
May 11 13:51:39 dido sshd[13443]: Failed password for root from XXXXXXXXXXX port 46038 ssh2
May 11 **11:51:39** dido sshd[13447]: Received disconnect from XXXXXXXXXXX: 11: Bye Bye
May 11 13:51:40 dido sshd[13467]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=XXXXXXXXXXX  user=root
May 11 13:51:42 dido sshd[13467]: Failed password for root from XXXXXXXXXXX port 46312 ssh2
May 11 **11:51:42** dido sshd[13473]: Received disconnect from XXXXXXXXXXX: 11: Bye Bye
```

As you can see, for the message "Bye Bye" it logged it with the UTC timezone instead of the GMT.

Thank you,
Mike

Comment: GMT and UTC are same time zone, unless fractions of second are of extreme importance to you.

Answer (score 0):

The Process-IDs don't match, so it looks like there are separate sshd processes each picking up different timezone settings.

For example: do you have one sshd started from /etc/rc, inetd or xinetd and another started manually on a different port, started from an interactive session (with a local TZ setting)?

Comment: I have looked at setting the clock on CentOS, and after several digging I have found out one problem that happens during the boot sequence. The _rc.sysinit_ script calls _hwclock_ and since this is a virtual image (a virtuozzo container) the file /dev/rtc doesn't exist and the command actually fails.


I ran a new _sshd_ process by "hand" with a custom configuration file (on localhost port 2222) and when the connection is lost it stills store a "Bye bye" message with the UTC clock.


I believe there is no way out of this, that it's a limitation of the virtualization of Virtuozzo.